# IntegrityError at /accounts/register/ NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_userbankaccount.gender

Tags: javascript, python, django, registration, integrity

while preparing registration form i cannot save/register a user. it is not saved in admin panel.it shows the above error.kindly help me.

VIEWS

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model,logout
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, RedirectView

from .forms import UserRegistrationForm

User = get_user_model()


class UserRegistrationView(TemplateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    template_name = 'accounts/user_registration.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse_lazy('transactions:transaction_report')
            )
        return super().dispatch(request,*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        registration_form = UserRegistrationForm(self.request.POST)


        if registration_form.is_valid():
           user = registration_form.save()
           user.save()

        #   login(self.request, user)
           messages.success(
            self.request,
            (
                    f'Thank You For Creating A Bank Account. '
                    f'Your Account Number is {user.account.account_no}. '
                )
            )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse_lazy('accounts:user_login')
            )

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                registration_form=registration_form,

            )
        )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if 'registration_form' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['registration_form'] = UserRegistrationForm()


        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)


class UserLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name='accounts/user_login.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = False


class LogoutView(RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'home'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            logout(self.request)
        return super().get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
```

MODELS

```
from decimal import Decimal

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.validators import (
    MinValueValidator,
    MaxValueValidator,
)
from django.db import models


from .managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def balance(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'account'):
            return self.account.balance
        return 0


class BankAccountType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    maximum_withdrawal_amount = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=12
    )
    annual_interest_rate = models.DecimalField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)],
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=5,
        help_text='Interest rate from 0 - 100'
    )
    interest_calculation_per_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(12)],
        help_text='The number of times interest will be calculated per year'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def calculate_interest(self, principal):
        """
        Calculate interest for each account type.

        This uses a basic interest calculation formula
        """
        p = principal
        r = self.annual_interest_rate
        n = Decimal(self.interest_calculation_per_year)

        # Basic Future Value formula to calculate interest
        interest = (p * (1 + ((r/100) / n))) - p

        return round(interest, 2)


class UserBankAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name='account',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    account_type = models.ForeignKey(
        BankAccountType,
        related_name='accounts',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    account_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    # gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICE)
    # birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(
        default=0,
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2
    )
    interest_start_date = models.DateField(
        null=True, blank=True,
        help_text=(
            'The month number that interest calculation will start from'
        )
    )
    initial_deposit_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.account_no)

    def get_interest_calculation_months(self):
        """
        List of month numbers for which the interest will be calculated

        returns [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12] for every 2 months interval
        """
        interval = int(
            12 / self.account_type.interest_calculation_per_year
        )
        start = self.interest_start_date.month
        return [i for i in range(start, 13, interval)]


# class UserAddress(models.Model):
#     user = models.OneToOneField(
#         User,
#         related_name='address',
#         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
#     )
#     street_address = models.CharField(max_length=512)
#     city = models.CharField(max_length=256)
#     postal_code = models.PositiveIntegerField()
#     country = models.CharField(max_length=256)

URLS

    from django.urls import path

from .views import UserRegistrationView, LogoutView, UserLoginView


app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "login/", UserLoginView.as_view(),
        name="user_login"
    ),
    path(
        "logout/", LogoutView.as_view(),
        name="user_logout"
    ),
    path(
        "register/", UserRegistrationView.as_view(),
        name="user_registration"
    ),
]

FORMS

from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import transaction

from .models import User, UserBankAccount
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus':'on'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'autofocus':'off'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': (
                    'appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 '
                    'text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 '
                    'rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight '
                    'focus:outline-none focus:bg-white '
                    'focus:border-gray-500'
                )
            })

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()

            UserBankAccount.objects.create(
                user=user,

                account_no=(
                    user.id +
                    settings.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_START_FROM
                )
            )
        return user
```

These are my codes.recently i removesome fields from registration form after that i can't save the user in admin panel.Registration form is not saved.kindly help me to find and correct my mistake

Comment: You need to run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` to sync your model changes to your DB

Comment: i migrated all just now. but my user details can't register..i can't save my registration form.facing same issue..  i can't save my form..help me

Comment: i can't understand where is the issue

Comment: pls help me to solve this